# Why does the EU have a huge amount of sanctions on Russia but not on the USA?

Tags: united-states, european-union, russian-federation, sanctions, visa

America has many times been seen intervening in countries without the approval of the current governments. Sometimes this has happened on blatantly far-fetched pretexts (chemical weapon in Iraq).

Why doesn't the EU unite and impose sanctions on Americans? For example the abolition of Schengen visas?

Comment: You might be interested: [Have there been any attempts by the rest of the world to sanction the US in the last years?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/43047/have-there-been-any-attempts-by-the-rest-of-the-world-to-sanction-the-us-in-the)

Comment: This question seems a fairly silly example of "whataboutism" I'm downvoting as lacking effort and not useful.

Comment: Reopen.  It's a fair question, though the answers given so far also answer it well enough:  because the disagreements are mostly not that big, and US misdeeds are generally nowhere near Russia's current malevolence.  Or at least not perceived as such by Western powers.  As for Yugoslavia, 1 word for you:  [Srebrenica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srebrenica_massacre).  Also, Schengen

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica this question is an example of standard russian narrative which they like to discuss on their propaganda TV. It attracts the same people who argue that both countries have done many things wrong and therefore what russia does is a good thing and should be accepted.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Oh, totally agree.  But the answers here make it clear that there are reasons why Russia in 2022 is not USA in 2003 and Zelenskyy in 2022 is not Saddam in 2003.  And why the Yugoslavia comparison is full of ....  Closing makes it seems as if the question needs to be avoided because of uncomfortable answers.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica unfortunately this is not how propaganda works. There will be 10 answers, one of them would be something like: `ah US has done a lot of shit but all countries do not care as they are all about money and they do not care about non-europeans`. It will be downvoted, but then upvoted with a couple of semi-fake accounts to get some positive score. And every propaganda puppet will claim that this is the main reason.

Comment: I highly doubt that the people who voted to close (not to mention the people who downvoted) as a push question are able to word this question such that it is no longer a push question. In other words, the reason this is a push question is because it's a question some people don't think should be asked. Italian Philosophers 4 Monica hit the nail on the head here, *Closing makes it seems as if the question needs to be avoided because of uncomfortable answers*.

Comment: @SalvadorDali We'll see.  Pro-Russian trolls have had a really hard time framing a coherent and credible position ever since the start of the war.  Doesn't help that if someone had told, 6 months ago, to my already anti-Putin self, what Russia would be up to these days, I would have laughed in their face for their rabid Russo-phobia.  It's just much worse than most would have imagined and, minus hefty censorship, it is hard to really "sell" the Russian PoV to a democratic audience.  So, let's not take away the trolls' opportunity to make fools of themselves spouting nonsense here.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica, as it was said earlier, this is not how propaganda works. A troll would never feel humiliated, its readers would never ridicule of a propagandist "made fools of themselves". It is either a "win", or a "he did not say that", or "okay he said, but that's not an issue". By giving them "an opportunity", **we're setting up ourselves to a loss**, or — at the very minimum — to "lucky you, it did not work this time, let me try once again". Sooner or later they will win; if not on the 1st "opportunity" then on the 10th.

Comment: @SalvadorDali "It attracts the same people who argue that both countries have done ..." And that's why it must remain open and be answered. Answering it is kind of trivial because both countries haven't done comparable things and the question would get asked anyway again and again, so we can as well answer it. That's why I voted to leave it open. But does that mean that I think this question is well researched and really useful? Rather no although I think that the answers should point to other more interesting questions, like e.g. why EU did not speak out more against the invasion of Iraq.

Comment: @bytebuster "Sooner or later they will win" (Might be more suitable for meta) Not as long as the majority of curating users here remain active and dedicated to the sites principles. This here is supposed to be a knowledge library. Every question that is ontopic should remain open and accept answers. The really cool thing though is that subsequent questions asking the same can be closed as duplicates. That seems to work quite well.

Comment: @uberhaxed sure I simplified a lot. But current political decisions are more influenced by what's in the collective memory (roughly the last hundred years) than the history of the centuries prior. And the level of brutality and quantity of crimes against humanity Russian armies displayed in their invasions is significantly worse than what Americans did in World War II in Europe, in Iraq, or in Afghanistan.

Answer (score 36):

Consider, say, the invasions of (say) Iraq and Afghanistan. The invasion was more-or-less seen as legitimate by most of the world at the time (and in particular by most of the **western** world, including the EU). The world also more-or-less believed that US intentions towards these countries was to eliminate a dangerous "rogue" government, set up a new democratic government, and leave the people of these countries to govern themselves in the long term.

In contrast Russia's invasion of Ukraine is seen as an illegitimate war of aggression by most of the world (and in particular by most of the **western** world, including the EU). The world also believes that the government Russia is opposing is a legitimate and democratic one, and that Russian intentions are to outright conquer Ukrainian territory and/or set up puppet states, for the advancement of Russian power and interests.

The situations simply aren't similar in the eyes of enough people/nations for it to seem at all reasonable to sanction the USA.

On top of that a number of EU nations were so convinced that these invasions were legitimate that they actively participated in them! So you definitely wouldn't see coordinated EU-wide sanctions against these invasions.

We can (but shouldn't here, on this site) debate how much of these perceptions are due to objective differences in the facts and how much are due to the EU being biased in favour of the USA and against Russia. I think it's pretty clear that there are such biases, but also that Russia's conduct is genuinely much further out of line with the EU's values than the USA's conduct was in its invasions (and therefore more worthy of being sanctioned in the EU's eyes).

Comment: Invasion of Iraq was not seen as a legitimate: France vetoed the UNSC resolution - hence the creation of the *Coalition of willing*, notable for some major western countries absent. This was widely recognized in the US at the time, as the Americans abroad would often apologize, and claim as an excuse that they didn't vote for GW Bush.

Comment: Also notably Germany took not part on the invasion of Iraq but that was more like abstaining instead of outright opposition.

Comment: @RogerVadim Yes, there are a lot of details I'm hiding under that "more-or-less" and "most of" because I don't want to write a book on the topic (and don't know enough to). It wasn't **universally** seen as justified, but widely enough that there certainly wasn't the large-scale consensus that the USA was acting wrongly and needed to be stopped, the way there is with Russia's invasion of Ukraine.

Comment: @Ben Sure, no one had any sympathy for Saddam. But the fact that he was seen as a bad guy, doesn't make the invasion legal/legitimate. Anyhow, I just find the wording of your first sentence misleading, but otherwise I do not have objections to your answer.

Comment: It's all about narratives! Western medias' dominance plays a key role here, regardless of whatever facts out there.

Comment: @Ben the invasion of Iraq it wasn't seen as legitimate at all. I doubt there were more countries in the world that considered it legitimate than there are countries that consider the invasion of Ukraine legitimate. Most especially in the EU, most countries except the UK and the government of Spain (but not the people, it was in fact the main reason that the then government was voted out of power) considered it illegitimate, actively opposed it and condemned it publicly.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions on how to word it, but I don't think I'm being inaccurate to say that the invasion of Iraq was perceived very differently at an international level than the invasion of Ukraine (and I'm not going to write a hugely detailed description of how it was received). Wikipedia lists 48 countries as **participating** in the invasion, including several other European ones (though I'm not sure exactly which ones were EU members at the time). The USA undoubtedly drove the invasion, but it was very far from being on its own in its position.

Comment: And I'm not saying that American **was** justified; I'm not from the US, and I did not personally agree with the war. I'm merely saying it was widely *seen* (by the kind of people who influence decisions about sanctions) as at least vaguely-kindof justified enough to meet the **very low** bar of not provoking massive internationally-coordinated sanctions. That is the limit of my claim.

Comment: @Ben that's the thing, I think you are being inaccurate. I was living between Spain and Greece at the time of the 2003 Iraq invasion, and in a very, very international environment and the feeling against the war in the general populace but also the press was very strong. We had most EU countries officially condemning it, France most vocally, others less so but the press was pretty damn clear on it even in those few countries whose governments supported it. And said support brought down the Spanish government directly, and the UK one only slightly less directly.

Comment: Maybe something like "more governments supported the Iraq war than the invasion of Ukraine"? It's the "*The invasion was more-or-less seen as legitimate by **most of the world** at the time [ . . . ] **The world also more-or-less believed** that US intentions towards these countries was to eliminate a dangerous "rogue" government....*" that I really object to as I think both claims are completely false.

Comment: @terdon please stop the ongoing and tedious discussion in comments. Downvote the answer. Give a reason if you wish, but there is NO need to engage in a rant against the answerer. Best of all? _Write your OWN answer._

Comment: @CGCampbell please relax a little. I am not ranting, and while your point about excessive discussion is both fair and valid, calling my comments a rant is a bit much. I have downvoted, and I also left _civil_ and not ranty comments with the specific issues I object to and a suggestion on how to improve the answer that the OP is of course free to ignore. So please don't YELL at me and don't mischaracterize polite disagreement as a "rant".

Comment: Also, the war in Ukraine is specifically about punishing Ukraine for wanting to join the EU (that's what the 2013 Euromaidan protests were about and the war is their direct consequence). Given that, it would be utterly foolish of the EU not to assert that it should be the member states, not Russia, who get to decide who can join the club.

Comment: Also it is less of a viewpoint and more a prediction when Russia has used the last 15 years to do land grab "protective military interventions" elsewhere in the post soviet world.

Answer (score 17):

The US and European countries share more than just *values*: there are shared economic interests and military alliances (notably NATO). Thus, while there have been disagreements between the US and its European allies, they rarely go as far as to impose sanctions on each other (Europeans also occasionally engage in military actions abroad, not always to the US's liking.)

To give a few examples:

- The invasion of Iraq was widely viewed as illegal, with France openly objecting the military action in the UN. The US had to scramble the *Coalition of willing*.
- Turkey, though not exactly a European power, has been a point of contention due to its likely human rights abuses, lacking in terms of democracy, and double dealing in military and diplomatic domains (with China, Russia, and Iran). On occasion, it found itself in outright confrontation with France and Germany. But Turkey is a major NATO player, and the sanctions have been very limited (mainly to public criticisms).
- AUKUS deal has been a major scandal between the US and France (seen particularly bad after the debacle with Mistrals - ships destined for Russia, which France refused to deliver to please the US, nearly resulting in the bankruptcy of the major shipyard). At the time, France recalled its ambassador to the US - an extraordinary step.
- A relatively dated affair is the Suez war, where British and French (acting jointly with Israel) were forced to withdraw after pressure by the US.

Comment: [AFAICT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mistral-class_amphibious_assault_ship), France changed their position on the Mistrals delivery in 2014, due to the annexation of Crimea. So just calling it a US-pleaser move may not quite hit the mark. Sticking to the delivery would have been like Nordstream 2, only worse from an optics persp., since the Mistrals were military ships. Germany also [blocked](https://www.army-technology.com/news/newsgermany-blocks-combat-simulation-equipment-export-to-russia-4334696/) the delivery of the final bits of a training centre for the Russian army, around that time.

Answer (score 11):

Various EU nations joined many of the US actions you complain about. The 1991 Gulf War was joined by France and the UK, then UK and Poland in 2003 (I guess that one is the war you mentioned), plenty of EU members joining in Libya, ...

The reason for that is that most EU members are far closer to the values of the United States than the values of Russia. [My Lai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%E1%BB%B9_Lai_massacre) and [Abu Ghraib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Ghraib_torture_and_prisoner_abuse) stand out because they are **not typical** for the conduct of US forces. While [Bucha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucha_massacre) seems to have been Russian government policy, considering how Russia [honored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64th_Separate_Guards_Motor_Rifle_Brigade#Russian_invasion_of_Ukraine) the involved unit.

Comment: The 1991 Gulf War was joined by Poland in 2003?

Comment: @gerrit I guess the two could be seen as a single war, just like the current Russia-Ukraine confrontation and the one in 2014 :) More seriously - 1991 invasion was actually legal... perhaps the only legal war in the UN history, for it was authorized even by the USSR.

Comment: @gerrit, the sentence mentions three wars. I would think the sentence is clear enough.

Answer (score 7):

Comparing Iraq (2003) with Ukraine is somewhat silly from a EU perspective because while France or Germany did not support that invasion, they were not willing to stake their relations with the US on sanctions what would have been perceived as supporting Saddam, a dictator who gassed thousands. Some EU countries like the UK (it was in the EU then) or Poland (which acceded to the EU around that time) participated in the US-led coalition from the start. (Ostensibly a sizeable part of Iraq was under Polish command at one point, as [this map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_zone_in_Iraq) had it.) After Saddam was "magically" gone from power (from the realpolitik perspective), several more EU countries sent troops to Iraq as well, to help the new Iraqi government. [Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Ancient_Babylon) and [Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_Ultra_Brigade) went in mid-2003 (although Spain also pulled out after a change in government back home, a year later). France and Germany indeed "held out" for much longer and (despite recognizing the new Iraqi government [in 2004](https://www.kuna.net.kw/ArticleDetails.aspx?language=en&id=1479322)) offered [only](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-2005-feb-23-fg-nato23-story.html) very limited participation in a small-scale and badly [underfunded](https://www.atlanticcouncil.org/blogs/natosource/natos-training-mission-in-iraq-faces-a-significant-shortfall/) training program for Iraqi forces under NATO umbrella... [until](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Op%C3%A9ration_Chammal) ISIS became a thing in Iraq, when France commenced combat operations too (of course, this was decade later). (Germany [was](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_intervention_against_the_Islamic_State) "pulled in" in a supporting role after ISIS retaliated on Paris.)

Comparing Ukraine 2022 with Yugoslavia is even more silly because almost every EU country sent troops to the various Yugoslav conflicts (mostly as peacekeepers, but one has to remember that peacekeepers were often taken hostage there and had to be rescued with airstrikes.) So on that the EU were much more aligned with the US. And yeah, Yugoslavia back when it existed, agreed to the foreign troop presence beforehand, albeit not without being bombed first. But this method of getting to the agreement [bothered not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_1244) the UN as a whole, when it came to endorsing the agreement. (And yeah, [headline](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/german-troops-return-bosnia-fear-instability-due-ukraine-war-grows-2022-08-16/) from yesterday "German troops back to Bosnia as fear of instability grows". If you're some kind of [SFRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_Federal_Republic_of_Yugoslavia) dieharder, that's another invasion to you, maybe?!)

Before someone complains about this, above I've simplified the Yugoslav history a lot, because that's the depth level of this Q. The Bosnian and Kosovo conflicts were fairly different in how they were approached by "the West" at least in terms of pacing: in the former relatively poorly equipped peacekeepers were either helpless bystanders to massacres or outright taken hostage in response to ["pinprick"](https://www.brookings.edu/articles/decision-to-intervene-how-the-war-in-bosnia-ended/) airstrikes. You could say there was a learning curve. While the bombing of Yugoslavia may look overkill in isolation, it was like that because Clinton ([said](https://youtu.be/rLzPVYTf2oc?t=251)  he) didn't want a repeat of years of Bosnia-like "peacekeeping" experience. Some Dutch leaders [nowadays](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-61855110) complain/argue that in Bosnia the bombs didn't fall soon enough and in enough quantity, e.g. to prevent Srebrenica. For the earlier Bosnia debates as phrased back then see ["lift and strike"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_and_strike_(Bosnian_War)). (The French were also more reluctant to agree to extensive bombing of Yugoslavia...
but in the end they approved of all the targets that were deliberately struck, in a fairly detailed review process that would be too long to cover here, but [is publicly known](https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/national/daily/sept99/airwar20.htm); this ultimately included power plants, bridges, and the TV towers.)

Comment: In three sentences, The EU and US support rule by the people corrupted as it may be. They have only invaded countries where popular movements are brutally hammered down and elections are rigged or non-existant. Russia invaded Ukraine for the opposite reason: Russia has practically never had free election process, and is hammering down Ukraine for having succeeded to organize two flawed but openly contested elections, where the Ukrainians decided that they want local rule, not dictated by communist tradition or moscow.

Answer (score 7):

**In Germany, the 2003 Invasion of Iraq was widely seen as illegimate and criminal act,** and in many aspects as similar to Russia's 2021 escalation of its invasion of Ukraine. German news unambigously revealed the US governments claims about WMDs in Iraw as lies. There were bigger protests on the streets than ever before. There was some opposition to Gerhard Schroeder's stance on the upcoming Iraq war from the conserative party, but this was less about the invasion being legitimate, but more about the US being a valued ally and "leader of the free world", who deserved some support even when doing wrong.

However, there was a widespread feeling of being **powerless compared to the US**. Putting economic sanctions on the US was not even discussed, because it was clear that they'd hurt Germany much more than the US. Even more so, Germany was not used to any kind of international leadership role, and many Germans felt doubtful whether Germany could be trusted with power if it had any. Still, this experience kick-started a push for the EU to take a role as a world power in its own right, so that it could eventually stand up to the US if necessary.

There are two more important differences: In 2003, **Iraq was led by a rather despicable dictator**. Once the US started the war, the best outcome clearly was to remove him from power and then get some kind of democratic government in place. So essentially, before the invasion noone was dieing yet, whereas afterwards it was too late to go back. In Ukraine on the other hand, a complete withdrawel of Russian troops is the desired outcome, hence continued action makes sense.

The last important aspect is that **the US is a democracy with a somewhat functioning opposition**. Eventually, the American voters got rid of GW Bush on their own accord; and there is probably no way that the European nations could have hastened that. It is worth pointing out that Obama was awarded the Nobel Peace Price for NOT being GWB.

Comment: The next Russian president, whenever that happens, could then also expect to get the Nobel peace prize for not being Putin.

Comment: @Trilarion not necessarily. As evil as Putin may be, Russia has enough people that would escalate the war further rather than stop it (e.g. the leaders of the PMCs fighting in Ukraine).

Comment: @Ruslan apart from a few clowns who just try to suck Putin's dick (medvedev, kadirov), a child who is disappointed that big boy is not paying attention to him (Strelkov) and propagandists who will shout at whomever the paying hand will tell (solovjev, skabeeva) I do not think that anyone will really like to escalate. It is clear that russia is no a force it thought it is. You wanted to conquer the whole Ukraine in 3 days and now you celebrate destruction of 1k people village.

Comment: @SalvadorDali and what about Prigozhin? And besides, if Girkin/Strelkov really somehow comes to power, he'll surely implement total mobilization. Can we be sure that such a crazy person won't be president?..

Comment: @Ruslan I think Prigozhin is in very peculiar situation and will not survive for long when Putin follows the step of Hitler/Mussolini. Officially Russia does not allow mercenary armies so he is a very nice scapegoat to be reprimanded and pushed many of the crimes on. Of course, everything is possible, but I do not think that Strelkov has chances. Right now the only thing he can do is to whine on the internet. He can't even move freely. I would put even 5% chances that he will not be alive in 6 months.

Answer (score 6):

**USA was successful in convincing EU that it's actions are legitimate and do not contradict traditional values of freedom and democracy.**

"has many times been seen" in the question refer to multiple cases that need to be analyzed each separately. Speaking about Iraq that is mentioned in the question, let's remember the historical context. Iraq it has been an aggressive dictatorship that invaded another country, Kuwait, so possessed obvious danger in the region. But it is clearly a separate topic.

Russia was not equally successful in proving the kindness of it's goals. Maybe if it would be the proof of grave atrocity, like Auschwitz for ethnic Russians running full steam 7/24 in Ukraine, we could indeed have seen EU joining on Russian side. I am not aware of any atrocities before the invasion.

Answer (score 3):

**Everyone is out for themselves.**

There are lots of reasons why it's in the EU's interests to have good relations with the US:

- Massive trade between the two.
- The US kind of covers Europe with its nuclear umbrella.
- Shared rivalries against Russia/China.
- And most importantly: the US is more powerful than the EU. That's why the US is widely regarded as a superpower and [the EU is not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_superpower#European_Union).

Accordingly, when the US does something the EU doesn't approve of (like invade Iraq or pull out of the JCPOA), they grumble. They complain. They make it clear they disapprove. But they don't actually impose sanctions, because God forbid the US imposes counter-sanctions. *That* would really make the EU's life hell. What small country pulls off sanctions against big countries anyway? You need collective action for that, and although it is possible the EU could've negotiated joint sanctions on the US with Russia/China with the aim of making the US suffer more than the EU does, those two countries are also strategic rivals (plus the EU would still suffer greatly).

You can see some parallel of this with the Russian sanctions. [141 countries voted in favor of United Nations General Assembly Resolution ES-11/1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_General_Assembly_Resolution_ES-11/1) condemning the invasion, but most of them didn't impose sanctions on Russia. They grumble, they complain, they make it clear they disapprove, but they don't actually impose sanctions because God forbid Russia imposes counter-sanctions.

You are not likely to see the EU impose sanctions on the US for any reason unless & until the EU starts to feel threatened by the US. US invades Iraq? Sure go ahead. US invades Afghanistan? Okay. US invades [Western-aligned European country]? Ok, *now* we are threatened, we'll impose sanctions.

Comment: Yes, everything if out for themselves. This is how everything works. But have you considered that there is a huge difference between terrorists actions of russia and between US? Or do you really consider them the same?

Comment: @SalvadorDali not the same, but similar - although when you use "terrorists actions" as the description I cease to be interested in any further discussion with you.

Comment: If you look long enough, you can find similarities between a rock and a spaceship. They are similar in a way that drunk fight in a bar is similar to a rape and subsequent killing of a child. BTW, feel free to explain how actions in Bucha, Irpin, castration/deliberate blow up of POWs, numerous missile strikes on hospitals, dormitories are not terrorist acts.

Comment: @SalvadorDali first let's hear you say that if those acts (which all allegedly happened post-invasion) had not happened, then the invasion of Ukraine is justified.

Comment: Allegedly? Are in the club of Soloviev who claims that that those things have not happened? Invasion of Ukraine is not justified on any conditions.

Comment: @SalvadorDali OK, so you say the invasion of Ukraine is not justified (and would not have been justified even if those things you cite never occurred). Now answer this one: do you think the invasion of Iraq in search of Saddam's non-existent WMDs was justified?

Comment: You have not answered whether you are in Soloviev club. Also, just to clarify, we are speaking about invading a country which was ruled by a guy who estimatedly (not allegedly) killed more than 200 thousand people, who supported terrorism, who invaded Kuwait. I am sure that if he would be alive now, he would be one of the friends of Putin. Yes, pretext for the attack (WMD was found to be wrong), but I am sure you are one of the people who think that Iraq with Saddam would be a way better place than without him.

Comment: @SalvadorDali I haven't answered it because it's not relevant. If you haven't realized, you've been arguing against a straw man. I was going to say, if you answered that invading Iraq looking for non-existent WMDs was not justified, then you see simple similarities between the two wars that you earlier denied were there. But you've decided to argue that invading Iraq was justified even with non-existent WMDs because the leader is a "bad guy". *That* would make the world a lot more dangerous because now all sorts of wars are justified. For example ...

Comment: Would you agree that the US should invade Russia now? After all, its leader is responsible for a war that has killed thousands, who "supported terrorism", who invaded Ukraine, and who is obviously good friends with Putin? What about China? Its leader is responsible for a cultural genocide in Xinjiang, who is good friends with Putin, etc. What about Iran? Uzbekistan? Would you invade them all? And if you answer "yes we should invade them all", then I'll argue that your ideology is much more dangerous to the world than what is going on in Ukraine.

Comment: It is very relevant. It is not possible to speak with an aryan brotherhood about holocaust, or with KKK supporter about moral issues of slavery. I think you need to refresh your definition of "bad guy". A person who dumps trash on the street is a bad guy, a guy who enjoys western values but supports totalitarian regime which kills thousand is a bad guy (probably way worth). A dictator who killed hundreds of thousands, who tortured and executed civilians in gas chambers, who genocided entire populations is not a 'bad guy'. He is a murderouse dictator, without him society would be way better.

Comment: Please go and read about all the shit that Saddam has done and then reply whether you think such person should continue to be in power even if he does not produce WMD. Also reply whether you denies the russian terrorist acts I wrote in comment 3 and the soloviev question. Now there are not many rules in the world whose action can come closer to what Saddam has done (Putin is trying his best and maybe soon he will reach that goal). To answer your questions (do not forget to not ignore mine). No, US should not invade Russia, but should sent troops to Ukraine to help. Same for China/Uzbekistan.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence about ideology is more dangerous - this is the stupidest thing I have read in a long time. You compare hypothetical thoughts with a full scale war which already produced thousands of death of civilians hundreds of war crimes and terrorist acts. You should really reconsider your thoughts.

Comment: @SalvadorDali Ok, let's change tacks. Please state exactly what you think it is that I have stated and believe, because the strawman coming from you is unbelievable. For example: do you think I believe that Russia is not a "bad guy"? If so, what's your justification for that? Find the exact quote.

Comment: @SalvadorDali what Saddam has done is irrelevant - he had a 100% approval rate among Iraqis before the US invasion. Iraqis were legitimately happy to have him as leader. You are imposing your moral values on others, you think others should believe what you do. I call that arrogance.

Comment: @SalvadorDali *You compare hypothetical thoughts with a full scale war which already produced thousands of death of civilians hundreds of war crimes and terrorist acts* If you insult a person hard enough and they assault you, is it your fault or theirs? I suppose you'll say it's theirs more than yours. I say the reverse. You provoked it, and while they aren't blameless, you hold more of the blame.

Comment: If it is hard for you to navigate though comments and find the questions, you have ignored, sure: Q1: explain how actions in Bucha, Irpin, castration/deliberate blow up of POWs, numerous missile strikes on hospitals, dormitories are not terrorist acts. Q2: do you believe that those things have not happened. Bonus Q3: do you think those 200k iraqies killed by Saddam also approved him? What about their families?

Comment: @SalvadorDali 1) Those are war crimes, not terrorist acts. 2) I think they probably happened. 3) Don't know, I don't have the data. But they presumably disliked the idea of US intervention even more.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside the reasons for the EU **to not have** such sanctions (such as common interests), there are no comparable reasons for the EU **to have** such sanctions.

The Russian Federation is not "intervening" in Ukraine.

- Russia is engaged in an **unprovoked aggression**
- with the **stated purpose** of naked **conquest of territory** which is legally Ukrainian and
- **destroying Ukrainian language and culture** in the process.  Russian state media and Russian parliament have made numerous proclamations to that effect.
- There is a preponderance of evidence of Russia engaging in a **campaign of terror** against Ukrainian civilians and of engaging in a
- systemic attempt at a **genocide** of the Ukrainian nation in violation of numerous treaties to which the RF is a party.

No war, and certainly no war in the recent history, or even in the modern history, fought by the United States, has even come close to meeting these criteria.

Russia is attempting to re-open the dark age of colonialism by mimicking its worst practitioner -- the Nazi Germany and the Empire of Japan, during its worst period of a turn to Fascism.  Short of the madness of these fascist overtures, one would have to reach centuries back to find an example of such moral degradation by a state claiming to have any kind of stake in the modern world.

The sanctions are meant to communicate to Russia and its people that these actions will not be tolerated.

At no point have the actions of the United States have required anything even remotely close to sending such a message.